# Any way to use a GridView DataField value as a SELECT parameter for another DataSource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, webforms

Is there a way; in asp.net syntax or C#, to use a data bound value from a GridView's DataField as a SELECT parameter for another data source?

I know you can use Control Parameter and Select based on the value of a control but what about Selecting based on the value of a particular DataField Value within a grid?

For example SELECT * FROM Table WERE X = 'GridView Value'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GridView` control, just like any other Server-Control, has properties which you can specify in the `ControlParameter` and use theirs values.

As for `GridView` control, the relevant property to use is the `DataField` which might have different values in each row.

Now, if you want this `DataField` to keep being editable when working in Edit mode, use this:

```
<SelectParameters>
<asp:ControlParameter Name="ProductID" Type="Int32" ControlID="yourOtherGridViewID" PropertyName="SelectedValue"></asp:ControlParameter>
</SelectParameters>
```

Otherwise, use this:

```
<SelectParameters>
<asp:ControlParameter Name="ProductID" Type="Int32" ControlID="yourOtherGridViewID" PropertyName="SelectedDataKey.Values('fieldname')"></asp:ControlParameter>
</SelectParameters>
```

**Using it, please notice that the values will be retrieved from the current selected row in the `GridView`.**

In addition, you will need to add each field that the `ControlParameter` needs to reference in the `GridView` control to the `DataKeyNames` property in this referenced `GridView`:

```
DataKeyNames="ProductID"
```

Comment: Brilliant. That worked. I was leaning towards a similar solution, using the GridView's ID as the control ID but I was not sure how to pick a particular field value.
Thank you.